# Laravel 5 route::resource to get three parameters

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Hi everybody i have problem with route when i try to get 3 parameters

```
LogicException in RouteCompiler.php line 102:
Route pattern "/api/comments/{commentableType}/{commentableId}/{{commentableId}}" cannot reference variable name "commentableId" more than once.
```

My route is :

```
Route::resource('api/comments/{commentableType}/{commentableId}', 'CommentController');
```

My service :

```
public function findById($class, $classId, $id, ApiRequest $request = null);
```

My ServiceImplement :

```
public function findById($class, $classId, $id, ApiRequest $request = null)
    {
         return  Comment::where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('commentable_type', $class)
            ->where('commentable_id', $classId)
            ->findOrFail($id);
    }
```

My Controller :

```
public function show($class, $classId, $id)
    {
        return $this->commentService->findById($class, $classId, $id, new ApiRequest());
    }
```

Comment: You passed the same variable `commentableId` twice, that 's why you are getting the error. Try something like `/{type}/{comment}/{id}`

Answer (score 0):

Your route only specify 2 parameters. But at your controller you try to take 3 parameters.

```
Route::resource('api/comments/{commentableType}/{commentableId}/{id}', 'CommentController');
```